# Node.js socket.io with React web worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a project to do with socket.io, React.js and Webworkers

[image]

Components A and B are child components of the Home page component. Also components A and B act as tabs. If A mounted, then B unmounted and wise versa.

When a component is initially rendered for the first time, the web worker should start pulling data from the socket.io server. Even after it's unmounted, data pulling should run in the background and when the user again mountss the same component data should be displayed which got from the web worker.

I have created a web worker like this

**rr-bf-worker.ts**

```
import { socket } from "../services/socket";

onmessage = function () {
  console.log("::RR/BF worker started...");
  socket.on("RR/BF-data", (data: [string[]]) => {
    postMessage(data);
  });
};
```

Then in the component

**rr-bf-table.tsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";
import ReusableTable from "./reusable/reusable-table";
export default function RRBFTable() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState<[string[]]>();

  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Here");
    const myWorker = new Worker("../workers/rr-bf-worker");

    myWorker.postMessage("start");
    myWorker.onmessage = (e: any) => {
      console.log("Time Taken", e.data);
    };
  }, []);

  if (typeof rows === "undefined") {
    return <p>Please wait...</p>;
  } else {
    return <ReusableTable rows={rows} />;
  }
}
```

But this doesn't even call the worker. What went wrong in the code?

This is [Full code](https://github.com/pathum-kalhan/socket.io-client)
Also, this is my [backend code](https://github.com/pathum-kalhan/socket.io-be) if needed

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using webpack so you have to import your worker like this (https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/):

```js
new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));
```

now I'm not sure what the url should be in your case, but I think one of these three should work:

```js
const myWorker = new Worker(new URL("../workers/rr-bf-worker", import.meta.url));
```

```js
const myWorker = new Worker(new URL("../workers/rr-bf-worker.js", import.meta.url));
```

```js
const myWorker = new Worker(new URL("../workers/rr-bf-worker.ts", import.meta.url));
```